# howler.js: Which event is fired (continuously) while audio is playing?

Tags: javascript, audio, event-handling, howler.js

I am using howler.js to play audio. The feature I am trying to implement is highlighting text while audio is playing. I have timestamped (start and end) json data for each word.

To achieve highlighting word(s) with the audio, one way that I thought of is to loop through the words, for each word, if the current seek time is within the bounded range of a word's start and end time, then I will change attribute of the word's `HTML SPAN`.

Shouldn't I need an event that keeps firing while the audio is playing? In other words, if my goal was to implement an audio seek bar, how would I achieve that goal? From the documentation of howler.js, the objective of `onseek` function is unclear, its not firing. Here's what I tried from the documentation.

```
sound = new Howl({
   src: ['output.mp3'],
   html5: true,
   onseek: function() {
     console.log('seeking...');
   }
});
```

Or should I be looking at something else?

Comment: Can you let me know if my answer solved your problem? And if so, could you please mark it as the answer? Thanks 

Comment: ...or don't I guess 

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the solution proposed in their [examples](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/blob/7c50da154af52bd4971ae75acbf6c078d256cd12/examples/player/player.js#L216)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onseek is triggered when the audio is scrubbed to a different position. Normal playback does not trigger the seek event.

What I would recommend instead is something like this...

```
function isPlaying(){
   if(sound.playing()){
      console.log('audio is currently playing...');
      setTimeout(isPlaying, 1000); //adjust timeout to fit your needs
   }
}

sound = new Howl({
   src: ['output.mp3'],
   html5: true,
   onplay: isPlaying
});
```

Here's a very basic and dirty demo showing that it works: [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QXGgQz)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and recommending an alternative. It works. Meanwhile, to get going, I got rid off howler.js and instead using html5 audio - very basic and neat!

Comment: Glad to hear you found something that worked for you! 